# Creating the onvif compliance camera using the GStreamer Pipeline

Tags: rtsp, gstreamer

I have a camera and I am streaming the video data using the GStreamer. With below pipeline.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e camerasrc ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8554
```

Now I would like to make the streaming ONVIF compliance. How I can do it with Gstreamer?